# Search for next blank cell in another sheets and paste

Tags: vba, excel

I am new using macro of Excel, and this is the first time I ask a question here.
I did some research here about this problem, but still can't solve it.

I have several sheets named :page 1, page 2, etc, and I want to copy the data in specific range and paste them to the sheets named "ULD".
When I run the macro in page 1, everything works perfect. But when I run it in page 2 or other sheet, the new data will paste and replace the data pasted from page 1.

The following is my vba code:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("ULD")

      'Only Copy Visible Cells'
  Range("L3:L100").Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  Selection.Copy

Sheets("ULD").Activate
   For Each cell In ws.Range("I4:I10").Cells
       If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select.Paste: Exit For
   Next cell

End Sub
```

Besides, I want the data being paste only value, how should I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion, this is how I interpret what you are trying to do.

```
Sub test2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LstRw As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("ULD")
    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'Only Copy Visible Cells'
    Range("L3:L100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ws.Range("I" & LstRw + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, it just occurred to me a question, what part of the code should I change if I  want  to add a range to this function, for instance: only working in C3 to C50 ?